# How to build a service which consumes an image with Jersey without using Multipart?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to make a service that consumes an image (binary data).

Using this code :

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes("image/jpg")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RolesAllowed({ Constants.SECURITY_ROLE_ADMIN })
public Response postRestaurantPicture(InputStream is)
{
    System.out.println("test");
    return Response.ok("it works").build();
}
```

Produces this error :

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unsupported Media Type</h1>
</body></html>
```

A hint is that I can't find a constant like MediaType.IMAGE_JPG like for MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.

1. Should I forget about consuming image/jpg or image/png directly ?
2. Should I use multipart/form-data ?
3. Should I use application/octet-stream and pass the image content-type in another header parameter ?

Comment: Try use `@Consume(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)`

Comment: Ok my bad, the client I was using (Advanced Rest Client) to try my service was forcing the request content-type to multipart/form-data so obviously it was not goint to work...

Answer (score 0):

I finally used this code which works perfectly :

```
@POST
@Path("/{entityId}/pictures/{pictureId}")
@Consumes({ "image/jpg", "image/png" })
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RolesAllowed({ MyConstants.SECURITY_ROLE_ADMIN })
public Response postRestaurantPicture(@PathParam("entityId") String entityId,
        @PathParam("pictureId") Integer pictureId, byte[] imageBytes)
{
/// ...
}
```